# Python : Input, Raw input error

Tags: python

I am trying a simple Hello world, this is my code-

```
def hello(name=''):
    if len(name) == 0 :
        return "Hello, World!"
    else :
        return "Hello, %s!" %(name)
my_name = raw_input()
x = hello(my_name)
print (x)
```

This code works fine if I use raw_input, but if I use input, it gives an error.
Doesn't the new python not support raw_input. 
I also want to know why I defined the parameter in my function as following-

```
def hello(name='')
```

Why did I need to use the '' after name

I am really confused, please help. If you have any advice to improve my program, it's appreciated

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't exist in "the new python" (Python 3), so you're using the "old" python (Python 2.x).

Comment: You've also lifted an example from somewhere, probably a tutorial that will go on to explain. `Why did I need to use the '' after name` is defining a default value for the function argument. `''` is simply an empty string, so if you called `hello()` and didn't pass an argument to the function, `if len(name) == 0` is `True`, so you'd get "Hello World!".

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing string with `input`, you have to also mention the double quotes `"`, for example `"My Name"`

Whereas in `raw_input`, all the entered values are treated as string by default

**Explanation:**

```
# Example of "input()"
>>> my_name = input("Enter Name: ")
Enter Name: "My Name"  
# Passing `"` with the input, else it will raise NameError Exception
>>> my_name
'My Name'   <--- value is string

# Example of "raw_input()"
>>> my_name = raw_input("Enter Name: ")
Enter Name: My Name
# Not passing any `"`
>>> my_name
'My name'    <--- still value is string
```

Comment: Could you explain the proper usage in my code ?

Comment: I am using Python 3, why doesnt input work for me ?

Comment: @p427h4ck3d0sh1: Updated the answer. Hope it may help

Comment: @p427h4ck3d0sh1 You're not using Python 3, otherwise "`raw_input` works fine" could not be true because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @p427h4ck3d0sh1 How are you running your code?